# Using the TBS (or equivalent parameter) in Google Custom Search

Tags: google-custom-search

When using **Google Custom Search** the TBM parameter for selecting specific types of search engines (e.g. tbm=pts for patents or tbm=blg for blogs) seems to be supported even though this isn't properly documented in the list of parameters.

However when using such "special" searches one usually extend the query by using the TBS parameter, unfortunately this doesn't work for me. For example:
`https://www.google.com/?tbm=pts&gws_rd=ssl#q=touch+screen&tbas=0&tbs=ptss:g,ptso:us&tbm=pts`
filters correctly when posted from a browser.

But the equivalent custom search:
`https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=*MY_KEY*&cx=*MY_ENGINE*&tbm=pts&q=lice+comb&tbs=ptss:g`
Completely ignores the TBS parameter.

Is there a way to specify an equivalent parameter in custom search?

Answer (score 1):

Set image search on in the Control Panel to generate a separate Image tab (can set to default). If you're editing an existing CSE, it's under Search Features in left-hand column, then click Imagesearch Settings. You can edit settings, but specifying image type (e.g., Faces) isn't one of them - also see https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2630972?hl=en&ref_topic=4513743 and https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/3037004?hl=en&topic=3036698
If you want to do additional things like that, you're probably better off creating a series of bookmarklets (easily shareable with a free tool like https://w-shadow.com/bookmarklet-combiner/ ) or via your own JS-enhanced webpage where you can build in all those parameters.