# Specifying a Date Range in Google Custom Search API

Tags: python, google-api-client, google-custom-search, google-api-python-client

It's trivial to search for a set of keywords in a certain website in a specific date range: in the google search box you enter

```
desired-kewords site:desired-website
```

then from the Tools menu you pick the date range.

e.g. "arab spring" search term in www.cnn.com between 1th Jan 2011 and 31th Dec 2013:

[image]

As you can see in the second picture there are about 773 results!
The search URI looks like this :

https://www.google.co.nz/search?tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2011%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2013&ei=iDcnWoy3Jsj38QW514S4Aw&q=arab+spring+site%3Awww.cnn.com&oq=arab+spring+site%3Awww.cnn.com&gs_l=psy-ab.12...0.0.0.6996.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.a4-ff19obY4

The date range could be seen in *cd_min* and *cd_max* of the tbs parameter (which appears in URI whenever the tools menu is used).

I would like to get the same functionality programmatically using Google's custom search API client for python.

I defined a custom search engine:

[image]

Then tried different suggestions I found on the web/stack overflow:

- [This is a related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27096026/using-the-tbs-or-equivalent-parameter-in-google-custom-search) question which is left unanswered.
- This post about [Date range search using Google Custom Search API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32406933/date-range-search-using-google-custom-search-api) referred to [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_data#page_dates) and suggests using the 'sort' parameter to do the favour (sort = 'date:r:yyyymmdd:yyyymmdd'). It did not work: "totalResults" is "44900".
- [This post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/customsearch/e5IYmR4U7k8) suggests using date restrict field which does not work as well.

Well! Any working solution?

Answer (score 3):

I might be late, but for other people searching for the solution, you can try this:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

my_api_key = "YOUR_API_KEY"
my_cse_id = "YOUR_CSE_ID"

def google_results_count(query):
    service = build("customsearch", "v1",
                    developerKey=my_api_key)
    result = service.cse().list(q=query, cx=my_cse_id, sort="date:r:20110101:20131231").execute()
    return result["searchInformation"]["totalResults"]

print google_results_count('arab spring site:www.cnn.com')
```

This code will return around 1500+ results.

It is still far from the web results, [Google has an explanation why](https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/70392?hl=en).

Also, if you haven't setup your CSE to search the entire web, [here's a guide on how to set it up.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082966/what-are-the-alternatives-now-that-the-google-web-search-api-has-been-deprecated/11206266#11206266)

*P.S. If you still want to get the web version's result/data, you can just scrape it using BeautifulSoup or other libraries.*

Answer (score 2):

In case you dont want to use SORT parameter you can insert date into your query parameter like:

```
https://customsearch.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?
key=<api_key>&
cx=<search_engine_id>&
q="<your_search_word> after:<YYYY-MM-DD> before:<YYYY-MM-DD>"
```